# Extract file from directory inside tar file without creating that directory

Tags: files, tar

I have a tarfile which has the following structure:

```
- dir1
 -- file
- dir2
- dir3
```

If I try running `tar -xf tarfile.tar.gz dir1/file`, dir1 containing the file will be created. I would like instead to just get the file without the directory in between. I could move the file and delete the directory, but I was wondering if the tar command offers support for doing that directly.

I am using Alpine Linux.

Comment: Does your system's version of `tar` support the `--strip-components` option?

Comment: It does on Ubuntu. However, I just realized that I won't be using ubuntu for this command, but Alpine instead. I need to recheck if there's support for it.

Comment: @steeldriver It is supported (I just need to upgrade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIXly (except for the `gunzip` part that is not a POSIX command):

```
gunzip < file.tar.gz | pax -rs'|.*/||' dir1/file1
```

With `bsdtar`:

```
tar -s'|.*/||' -xf file.tar.gz dir1/file1
```

With GNU `tar`:

```
tar --transform='s|.*/||' -xf file.tar.gz dir1/file1
```

With `star`:

```
star -s '|*/||' -x -f file.tar.gz dir1/file1
```

Note that for some of those, if the file is a a symlink, the substitution will also affect the target of the symlink.

Comment: tar --transform works on Alpine (after upgrading). I ended up using the suggestion in the comments, but I will accept your answer since it also works.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract to stdout (-O) and pipe it to the wanted filename.

Comment: Though that would only work for regular files and you'd loose the file metadata (ownership, time, permission...).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Ruby. I make no attempt to handle sym-links properly, but that could be added of course.

```ruby
outfiles = `tar zxvf #{ARGV[0]}`
root_dirs = {}
outfiles.each_line do |l|
  s = l.split('/')
  root_dirs[s[0]] = 1
  `mv #{l.chomp} ./#{s[-1]}`
end
root_dirs.each_key {|rd| `rm -rf #{rd}`}
```